# Sampling according to a difference of two normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling

Assuming that I have two normal distributions $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$ and I can draw samples efficiently from them.

Now, I can easily draw samples from $p(x) = 0.5 p_1(x) + 0.5 p_2(x)$ by with probability = 50% taking a sample from $p_1$ and probability = 50% taking a sample from $p_2$.

Is there any similar way that I can efficiently draw samples from a difference of two distributions? For example $p(x) = 1.5 p_1(x) - 0.5 p_2(x)$, assuming that $p(x) > 0$?

Comment: Note that your proposed method to sample from the positive mixture is incorrect, because in any random sample it is more likely than not that one of the mixture components is represented *more* than the other. Just consider the problem you run into for a sample size that is an odd number!  Are you sure you are not confusing mixtures with *linear combinations* of random variables?  The sum (or mean) of two normal variates does *not* have the average of the PDFs for its PDF.

Comment: I think I made a mistake when saying "with 50% taking..". I meant for each sample, I flip a coin and with probability = 50% I get that sample from $p_1(x)$ and with probability = 50% I take from $p_2(x)$.

Comment: Ok, that's a mixture and *now* you have correctly described how to draw a sample from it (which differs from the description in the question). But then what does "$1.5p_1(x)-0.5p_2(x)$" mean? You can't flip a coin having probabilities of $1.5$ and $-0.5$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in general, since there will typically be areas where the density is negative, making it not a valid pdf.

[image]

In cases where $p(x) = 1.5 p_1(x) - 0.5 p_2(x)$ is sure to be non-negative, it's at least a density, and you can generate samples from it, for example by accept-reject (e.g. using $1.5 p_1(x)$ as majorizing function).

Comment: Thanks! We do have the constraint that $p(x)$ is positive. I have thought about rejection sampling; however this is a bit inefficient. Thus, I was looking for some direct sampling strategy similar to the case of mixture distribution.

Comment: But it's not a mixture. The naive accept-reject I suggested will accept 2/3 of points, which is pretty decent. More efficient approaches (mostly more efficient forms of accept-reject) could be constructed for particular cases, but at best you can only go from 2/3 to 1 anyway.

Comment: I found a related problem here [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22871/efficient-sampling-of-a-mixture-model). I think I will stick with rejection sampling. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I understood that post correctly, the algorithm there is the same naive accept-reject with c=1.5 that I suggested above.

Comment: Yes, that is the same with your suggestion. Thanks